# Understanding the Ruby method #call

Tags: ruby

```
def test
  "Hello World"
end

p method(:test).call  #"Hello World"
p method("test").call #"Hello World"
```

My question is: what happens when we pass a symbol to the `call` method? Will ruby convert the symbol to a String and then execute it? If so, then what is it's purpose?

And if not, then what actually happens? 
Can you please elaborate? 
Sorry if I fail to make myself clear.

Comment: Whatever it does is done internally to Ruby in C. It shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 15):

When you execute `def test ...` outside of any explicit class or module definition, you are essentially in the Object class context, so `test` is now an instance method of `Object`

In `irb` ...

```
1.8.7 :001 > def test
1.8.7 :002?>   "Hello world"
1.8.7 :003?>   end
 => nil
1.8.7 :004 > Object.instance_methods.sort
 => ["==", "===", "=~", "__id__", "__send__", "class", "clone", "display", "dup", "enum_for", "eql?", "equal?", "extend", "freeze", "frozen?", "hash", "id", "inspect", "instance_eval", "instance_exec", "instance_of?", "instance_variable_defined?", "instance_variable_get", "instance_variable_set", "instance_variables", "is_a?", "kind_of?", "method", "methods", "nil?", "object_id", "private_methods", "protected_methods", "public_methods", "respond_to?", "send", "singleton_methods", "taint", "tainted?", "tap", "test", "to_a", "to_enum", "to_s", "type", "untaint"]
```

`method` is an instance method of the `Object` class which is inherited by essentially everything. When you call `method` outside of any explicit class or module definition, you are essentially invoking it as a method of the `Object` class, and that class is itself an instance of `Class`, which is a subclass of `Object` (sorry -- I know that's a bit confusing to follow).

So -- the `method` method takes a string or a symbol and returns an object encapsulating the bound method of that name on the same object that `.method` was called on. In this case, that's the `test` method bound to the `Object` object.

`method(:test).call` means call the `test` method of `Object` which is what you defined previously via `def test ...`.

Comment: @MisterCal From the irb console, `Object.class` => Class .

Comment: Ah! Deleted. I made an assumption based on the fact that Object is a superclass of Class. I see now, bit confusing haha.